# Convert System DateTime to specific format. eg:(yyyyMMdd hh:MM:ss)

Tags: c#

I have problem in converting system datetime format to specific format.

for eg: `DateTime dt=new DateTime();`// It will return 11/15/2016 10:23 AM as per my system format.

But I have to convert into this format-- **20161115(yyyyMMdd hh:MM:ss)**. I can able to achieve  this using `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:MM:ss")? .

But its returning **String** format. I want in **DateTime** format.

Comment: DateTime will never have a formatting when not converting to string. Does double or int has a formatting when not converting to string? [MSDN - Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The `DateTime` object have values in its properties, You want it to represent the data in a particular format, SO you use `ToString()` But that doesnt change the content of the Object. You are just displaying it in diff format.

Answer (score 5):

`DateTime` as an object *has no format*. It contains the information as an internal numeric valus and is only formatted to string representation by your IDE or code. You don't change the format for it.

Only when you want to *output* it somewhere you set the format and you get a string for it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `DateTime` is an object. That means the values are saved into its properties shown below.

If you want the DateTime to display in a different format than the default format then you use the `ToString(yourFormat)` method to format it. **That will not change the data or the position of the properties if thats what you are expecting**. (*the term position of the properties itself is meaningless*)

Its just representation. Just like how you have data in you database as tables but in UI you show it as a fancy HTML.

Internally the object saves data into each property and provides a default representation of it `DateTime.Now.ToString()`, And only when you dont want the default `DateTime` format you have the flexibility to format it into your choice.

So if your idea was to use this `string` date time for any code logic then you will just parse it into `DateTime` object by giving it the format the string is in like

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "yyyyMMdd hh:MM:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Now your string data is parsed into object and you can fetch the values as

`date.Date` , `date.Millisecond` etc

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
string str = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:MM:ss");

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMdd hh:MM:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: You can use this to read back the string to a DateTime format. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) is a class with various properties and methods associated with it.  You can't really return a DatTime object in a different "format" - it is just a representation of a point in time.  You can however, represent a DateTime object as a stirng foramtted in a specific way.  So what you are doing is correct:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:MM:ss")
```

Do this when you need to display the DateTime in a readabel format, such as in a log file or on a UI.  If you need to pass a DateTime as a parameter, pass the entire object, not just a string representation of it.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd hh:MM:ss", null);